# Which adaptations include Tom Bombadil?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, adaptation-comparison, tom-bombadil

When it comes to adapting *The Lord of The Rings*, Tom Bombadil has a habit of [not making the cut](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QxhP7F1CftE).

Are there any adaptations that do feature him?

### Which adaptations of *The Lord of The Rings* include Tom Bombadil?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

More than you might think, though most of them are video games only tangentially related to *The Lord of the Rings* novels.

In no particular order:

- *The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring*, a 2002 video game not based on the film
- *The Lord of the Rings: The Battle for Middle-Earth II*, a 2006 video game
- *The Lord of the Rings: The Battle for Middle-earth II - The Rise of the Witch-king*, a 2006 expansion to the above game
- [*Hobitit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobitit), a 1993 Finnish miniseries
- The 1979 [Mind's Eye recordings](http://www.sf-worlds.com/lotr/minds-eye-1979/), an NPR radio series
- The 1955 BBC radio series. This one had the distinction of being heard by Tolkien, who didn't care much for Bombadil's voice actor:

  > I  think the book quite unsuitable for 'dramatization', and have not enjoyed the broadcasts - though they have improved. I thought Tom Bombadil dreadful - but worse still was the announcer's preliminary remarks that Goldberry was his daughter (!), and that Willowman was an ally of Mordor (!!)
  >
  > <sup>*The Letters of J.R.R. Tolkien* 175: To Molly Waldron. November 1955</sup>
- [*The Lord of the Rings Online*](https://lotro-wiki.com/index.php/Tom_Bombadil), the 2010 [MMORPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massively_multiplayer_online_role-playing_game) that has somehow managed to avoid being beaten into submission by *World of Warcraft*
- The [Games Workshop](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Games-Workshop-Lord-of-the-Rings-Tom-Bombadil-LoTR-Metal-Figure-OOP-/262171145753?hash=item3d0a9e3619:g:jvIAAOSwAKxWXnGZ) Warhammer clone
- The LEGO video game adaptations of [*The Lord of the Rings*](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/lego-lord-of-the-rings/Middle-earth_Unlocks) and [*The Hobbit*](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/lego-the-hobbit/Tom_Bombadil?objectid=20008981); he appears as an unlockable character, and in the overworld of the games, but does not appear in the story mode<sup>1</sup>
- A [1969 *Harvard Lampoon* parody *Bored of the Rings*](http://www.theguardian.com/books/booksblog/2011/feb/08/tolkien-bored-of-the-rings) (as Tim Benzedrine)
- The 1992 [*Tales of the Perilous Realm*](http://www.tolkienlibrary.com/press/853-Tales-Perilous-Realm-BBC-Dramatization.php), a BBC Radio dramatization of some of Tolkien's lesser-known poems, and the Bombadil segment of *Fellowship of the Ring*
- [*War in Middle-Earth*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_in_Middle_Earth), a 1988 video game released on early PCs (including the Commodore 64 and the ZX Spectrum)
- [*Lord of the Rings: Volume I*](http://www.lysator.liu.se/tolkien-games/entry/lotr1.html), a 1990 video game released for DOS and, later, the Commodore Amiga; not to be confused with the [1994 SNES game of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J.R.R._Tolkien%27s_The_Lord_of_the_Rings,_Vol._I_(SNES_video_game))<sup>2</sup>
- [An operatic adaptation of the Bombadil chapters](http://www.tolkienlibrary.com/press/956-Interview-with-Paul-Corfield-Godfrey.php)
- The [1992 German radio play](http://www.randomhouse.de/Hoerbuch/Der-Herr-der-Ringe/J.R.R.-Tolkien/der-Hoerverlag/e387241.rhd)<sup>3</sup>
- [Middle-Earth Role Playing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-earth_Role_Playing) (a tabletop RPG)<sup>4</sup>; so far I've been able to confirm his presence in the following sourcebooks:

  - [*Lords of Middle-earth Volume 1*](http://www.waynesbooks.com/MERPSourcebooks.html)
  - [*The Shire*](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/thing:43755:moreinfo)

---

<sup>1</sup> For the unitiated, the gist of the *LEGO X* games is that the plot of the work being adapted is divided into a small number of playable levels, separated by an [overworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overworld). You play each level with the characters canonically present for the events it depcits, and after completing a level you're allowed to replay it with any characters you've unlocked. Some characters are unlocked by playing the levels in story mode, but some (like Bombadil) are just standing in the overworld and have to be purchased with the in-game currency

<sup>2</sup> I don't even have a witty remark to that. Just...*what*?

<sup>3</sup> Thanks to Jörg W Mittag for pointing this one out in comments

<sup>4</sup> Thanks to Ian Thompson for pointing this one out

Comment: LOTRO was never in the same league as WoW in terms of user numbers, it's not a valid comparison ;)

Comment: What's so surprising about the Lord of the Rings Volume 1 game? Sadly it didn't get completed. Volume 2 The Two Towers was rushed out with bugs in it. Certainly not "tangentially related"

Comment: ***I think the book quite unsuitable for 'dramatization'...*** Amen, brother. Amen.

Comment: @Ber The game itself doesn't surprise me, it's that two largely dissimilar games with the *exactly* the same name were released by the same publisher within only a few years of each other.

Comment: Yeah the PC game was poorly marketed... they might have actually lost control of the title!  It'd be interesting to see how weird the SNES game was from the era of weird Nintendo games, tho.

Comment: @user16295 though I played WoW for only one year and am still playing LOTRO since beta. And regarding Bombadil it is one of the most faithful adaptations I've seen.

Comment: He's mentioned in [*The Lord of the Rings*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_of_the_Rings_(musical)) musical.

Comment: @RogueJedi I saw that as well, but decided to leave it out; partially because Bombadil doesn't actually appear, and partially because I struggled to find a non-Wikipedia source confirming the mention. The frustrating thing is that I actually saw that play, but it was so long ago I don't remember the line